Reading String and double values into vectors using while loops and std::cin
I am doing self-directed exercises from Stroustrup's Programming principles and Practice Using C++.
The prompt for the exercise is as follows:

Design and implement a Name_pairs class holding (name,age) pairs where name is a string
and age is a double. Represent that as a vector (called name) and a vector
(called age) member. Provide an input operation read_names() that reads a series of names.
Provide a read_ages() operation that prompts the user for an age for each name. Provide a
print() operation that prints out the (name[i],age[i]) pairs (one per line) in the order determined
by the name vector. Provide a sort() operation that sorts the name vector in alphabetical order
and reorganizes the age vector to match. Implement all ‘‘operations’’ as member functions.

I am using the "std_lib_facilities.h" provided on the authors website. https://www.stroustrup.com/programming_support.html
I have created a Name_pair class with two private members and the  definitions for the relevant public methods  shown below
class Name_pairs {
  public:
  void read_names();
  void read_ages();
  void sort();
  void print();

  private:
  vector<string> name;
  vector<double> age;
  void check_sizes() {
    // error checking for mismatched pairs
    if (name.size() != age.size()) {
      error("Unequal number of names and ages"); // error is an author provided exception thrower
    }
  }
};

void Name_pairs::read_names() {
  string current_name;
  cout << "Enter a series of names: ";
  while (cin >> current_name) {
    name.push_back(current_name);
  }
}

void Name_pairs::read_ages() {
  double current_age{};
  cin.clear();
  cout << "Enter a series of ages: ";
  while (cin >> current_age) {
    age.push_back(current_age);
  }
}

void Name_pairs::print() {
  check_sizes();
  for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "Name: " << name[i] << " Age: " << age[i] << '\n';
  }
}

my main looks like this:
int main() {
  try {
    Name_pairs pair_list;
    pair_list.read_names();
    pair_list.read_ages();
    pair_list.print();
    return 0;
  } catch (exception &e) {
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
  } catch (...) {
    cout << "Unkown exception\n";
  }
}

when I compile and run the code I enter in the names on one line seperated by spaces ex: Tom Mary Adam then press enter. I have also tried entering names on seperate lines  I am using the ctrl-D command on a Linux Machine to stop reading the string input as that sends an EOF character to stdin. I attempt to clear the buffer in the read ages method but even after doing that the program prompts for ages then does not allow for new input and throws the check_size error.
I am aware of operator overlaoding and more sophisticated i/o methods such as getline and sstream.
I do not want to use those and I want to stick with the conventions presented in the book at this point. What I want is to be able to enter space or newline values, Hit ctrl-D and have my program actually stop to let me input numbers.
How can I clear the buffer to allow for this?
when I compile and run the code I enter in the names on one line seperated by spaces ex: Tom Mary Adam then press enter. I have also tried entering names on seperate lines  I am using the ctrl-D command on a Linux Machine to stop reading the string input as that sends an EOF character to stdin. I attempt to clear the buffer in the read_ages method but even after doing that the program prompts for ages then does not allow for new input and throws the check_size error.

This seems a questionable design. Rather it seems you'd want a struct/class that pairs a name and an age, and then a single vector of those.

It's easier to use a sentinel value like a blank line rather than relying on undoing ctrl-d

cin.clear() function do clear the error flags on cin so that further input operations can be performed, but if there are characters left in the input buffer, they will remain there and could interfere with subsequent reads. So you may need cin.ignore() after cin.clear().
void Name_pairs::read_ages() {
  double current_age{};
  cin.clear(); 
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Ignore characters up to the end of line.
  cout << "Enter a series of ages: ";
  while (cin >> current_age) {
    age.push_back(current_age);
  }
}

